# Create pivot chart comparing income and expense data

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel spreadsheet for keeping track of income and expenses for my small side business. I'm trying to create a clustered bar chart that shows my income and expenses grouped by month/year.

The Income table looks like this:

[image: Income Table]

And the Expense table looks like this:

[image: Expense Table]

What I would like is something like this:

[image: Chart]

Where the blue is my expenses and the red is my income.

The problem is, I don't know how to create a relationship between the income items and the expense items, because Date has duplicates.

What I'm currently doing is creating a pivot table for income and expense with rows being the month/year and the only column being the sum of the total for that month, then copying the raw data into a separate table manually.  This works, but there has to be a better way!

is there a way to create this relationship with the two raw data tables?

I come from a SQL background, so Excel sometimes gets me a little frustrated.

Comment: From an accounting perspective, and less of an Excel one - Are you on a Cash basis, or an Accrual basis? Does the matching principle apply at all to what you're doing, or is it just cash in, cash out?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example of when to use Power Pivot.

Add both Income and Expense tables to the data model.

Create a DATE table, and add that to the data model. Mark it as DATE table.

Create relationships between Date and Income, and Date and Expense:

[image: Relationship between tables in Power Pivot]

Now you can create a Pivot Chart based on the Data Model, and include elements from any of the tables.

[image: Pivot Chart based on data model, with values from all three tables]

I've added a couple of explicit measures to the model:

```
Total Income:= SUM ( Income[Total] )
Total Expense:= SUM ( Expense[Total] )
```

Worked example file available [HERE](http://excel.solutions/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/PowerPivotExample.xlsx)

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of stuff with Excel it's often easier and cleaner to put all your entries in the same table. You can add a column to specify whether it's an Income line or an Expense line.

However, there is a solution for what you're asking for.

First rename your "Total" columns into "Income" and "Expense". You need unique fields.

When you create a pivot graph, select "Add this data to the data model". Then in the Pivot Graph Fields menu, you will have the "all" option. There you will be able to select the data from every table in the document.

[image]

In Excel 2016, you will automatically have the month and year fields available. For earlier versions, you may have to add those columns (but you can compute them with the month() and year() functions and hide the columns).

See [that link](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/excel-2013-pivot-table-from-multiples) for details.